# Assigning value based on multiple selection from the user - using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am in a situation where i need to use a matrix/table and then assign a user a number mentioned in a  matrix(show below) based on user input provided.

This is the **matrix** (*kindly click on the image to zoom in*)-
 [image: the matrix table]

So,basically..

1. User lands on a webpage with multiple checkboxes and radio buttons,each asking few questions and user have to select answer as YES or NO.
2. After that,user clicks on calculate my rating button,and then this data comes to me .
3. So here is my question ---- how should i handle the user data and provide him the rating based on his selection.

i came up with few approaches...

1. Define few json structures of user input for each rating value.

   `{"list": [
     {
       "user-data": "user_name_timestamp",
       "inputs": [
         {
           "selected": [
             {
               "do_you_drink_occasionally": "yes",
               "do_you_spend_more_than_100": "no"
             },
             {
               "do_you_smoke_more_than_5": "no",
               "do_you_spend_more_than_50": "yes"
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   ]}`

   and then directly compare each and every value.
2. Get an array of user inputs and then compare and find user selected inputs and then provide the required rating.

**I am not sure if this is ok or is there more appropriate method to handle a scenario where you have to resolve a matrix based on inputs.**

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are they all going to be yes/no answers or are there going to be string/number inputs too?

Comment: They can be anything..either 1/0 or yes/no..i can configure it as required.

Comment: If they're simple yes/no answers, I feel like a multidimensional array is the simplest as you can just convert the yes/no to 1/0 and then just `result[first][second][third]` etc. I feel that JSON might be overly convoluted in comparison as all they do is store the selected options, which you then need to process anyway.

Comment: It sounds good,but if you can help me with an example,that would be great  :)

Comment: depends what you need. Could you provide perhaps what happens when all your options are selected what output it would give (e.g. yes, yes, yes = "you are fat") or whatever. And if (yes, yes) would equate to anything (could be just null)

Comment: well ,it wil be yes...so all checkboxes and radiobuttons that user click will give my form value of yes/no ..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this first:

```js
var array = new Array(2);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 array[i] = new Array(2);
}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
  {
    array[i][j] = new Array(2);
  }
}

//define what you want the end options to be

array[1][1][1] = "You eat too much, you are fat"

console.log(array);
```

So what this does is that if all the options are true (assuming your answers yes = 1 and no = 0). You can quickly access the corresponding answer.

You will need to set each final option.

So I'm assuming that one question correlates with the next so for example.

Q1. Do you drink?
Q2. Do you smoke?
Q3. Do you do drugs?

(Assuming all yes)

```
var q1 = 1
var q2 = 1
var q3 = 1

array[q1][q2][q3] // Should print out "You eat too much, you are fat"
```

Comment: This looks good.How this goes with the input parameter..are we traversing through the user selected params....?Can you add a bit more descriptive example and comment in it...

Comment: accesses the answer using the given responses, not sure how they are arranged on your end but I editted to give a rough example

Comment: What does the first and second loop does.Will this approach help for multiple yes/no...? If there are 6 options,will i have to define 6 different final answers,if i use this approach.. ?

Comment: depending on how the answers differ depending on the choices, it will be easier to use a multi-dimensional array, or just check all the options. If every single choice along the path creates a different answer at the end, a multi-dimensional array should be best, but if there are only a few answers in the end, then a switch should be easier